# How to make my petals stop floating in the air

Tags: particles

I use the particles system to make a flower, but all petals are floating, I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the origin of your petal object is below the mesh. Move it up (into the petal mesh narrower end) and you'll have the problem solved.

Comment: ..that is.. .just for complete clarity.. in Edit Mode, move the mesh _down_ with respect to its pivot point. Or in Object Mode, snap the cursor onto the petal where you would like the attachment point to be, and use Shift-Ctrl-Alt-C > Origin to Cursor.